# How to install NuGet-packages without internet connection?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget

Currently I'm developing on a virtual pc which is not allowed internet access. I managed to get the NuGet.Tools.vsix to add NuGet to Visual Studio 2010, but cannot seem to find out how to deploy NuGet-packages offline.

For example, I downloaded EntityFramework 5.0.0 [nuget.org](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/5.0.0) and moved it to my virtual pc. How should I perform the last step of deploying this package to my solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) you can read how to create local `NuGet` feed. Hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

1) Tools - > Options -> Package Manager

2) Then click Source and **Add**.

3) Then You can find on the list and istall.

Comment: I've found that option too somewhere, but forgot to mention. I don't have this option 'Package Manager' in the list...