# Add object to Entity Framework dynamically using Reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, system.reflection

In the following code, the type of `domainObject` varies (but ends with `DO`, which I trim then to get the corresponding table name). Having the name of the table and its type, I want to update an existing object - its name is the same as the `tableName` due to the EF - in the database with the new property values from `domainObject`. Therefore, I have to find the POCO in the table with the same `ID` first to overwrite this. This is the code so far:

```
public void Update(object domainObject)
{
  Type type = domainObject.GetType();
  string tableName = type.Name.Substring(0, type.Name.Length - 2);
  PropertyInfo tableProp = typeof(MyDbContext).GetProperty(tableName);
  Type tableType = tableProp.PropertyType;
  Type pocoType = tableType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

  int id = (int)type.GetProperty("ID").GetValue(domainObject);

  using (var context = new MyDbContext())
  {
    object table = tableProp.GetValue(context);
    MethodInfo singleMethod = tableType.GetMethod("Single");
  }
}
```

Usually, knowing the actual table and not just its type, I would now get the POCO via

```
var poco = context.TableName.Single(item => item.ID == id);
```

There's 2 problems here:

(1) `Single` is an extension method.

(2) I don't have an idea how to get the lambda expression in form of an `object` to pass it to the `Invoke` of `Single`.

Is there any way to do this at all with Reflection, or do I have to work around this? (For example, I could iterate through the items in `table` and check manually [which would load everything from the DB into memory and thus should be avoided], or maybe configure the EF to do some kind of 'override' whenever I just `Add` and object whose `ID` is already present if this is possible). Even supposing I could work around this, I'd still like to know a definitive answer to this question, since it's pretty interesting for me!

Comment: Working with generics would look like a muuuuch better idea...

Comment: How bout just working with the DbEntry?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Could you elaborate on that? I'm quite new to all this, so I only got to know (a bit) the Entity Framework 6 and I'm surely missing a lot of perspectives there.

Comment: What are trying to achieve using reflection to add object in entity framework?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I twisted my mind thinking about how to do exactly this, but I can't see a way. I get these objects from a `WebDataGrid` in an ASP.NET application that has an `IList` as DataSource that is switched, so there is no fixed type I can pass as generic (or don't know how to).

Comment: @JanneMatikainen I use reflection because what (type of the object to insert) and where (what table to insert into) to insert is determined at runtime and not before.

Comment: @InvisiblePanda I've included a answer with a solution that uses generics, and avoids reflection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use reflection and to find given entity by ID then, if ID is primary key this is fairly simple as this is all you have to do:

```
object entity = context.Set(domainObject.GetType()).Find(id);
```

If your property is not primary key then you need to do it as follows:

```
ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(domainObject.GetType());
Expression property = Expression.Property(p, "ID");
Expression c = Expression.Constant(id);
Expression body = Expression.Equal(property, c);
Expression exp = Expression.Lambda(body, new ParameterExpression []{ p });

MethodInfo singleMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
    .Single(m => m.Name == "Single" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2)
    .MakeGenericMethod(domainObject.GetType());

DbSet dbSet = context.Set(domainObject.GetType());
object entity = singleMethod.Invoke(null, new object[]{ dbSet, exp });
```

First with `Expression` class you build expression that will be passed to `Single` method (in your case this will be `p => p.ID == id`). Then you search proper `Single` method from `Queryable` class. The last thing is to invoke this method with proper parameters. This way you may do any linq queries with use of `Reflection`.

Comment: Oh great, I didn't know about the `Set` method; I can't test it right now, but as soon as I can I will, and - given it works - accept this answer :-) In my case I can even just pass `pocoType` to `Set` as this is what's in the table.

Comment: This works for sure. But I am going as well to present more general solution to your problem that will allow searching by properties that are not primary keys.

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to make a generic method, with a type parameter that represents the type of your entity and use the corresponding DbSet.

```
public int Update<TEntity>(TEntity domainObject)
{
  int id = domainObject.Id; // Needs interface !!
  using (var context = new MyDbContext())
  {
    var objectInDb 
       = ctx.DbSet<TEntity>.Single(e => e.Id == id);  // Needs interface !!
    // Use ValueInjecter (not AutoMapper) to copy the properties
    objectInDb.InjectFrom(domainObject); // needs ValueInjecter Nuget Package
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
  return userId;
}
```

As you see in the code comments, your entities need to implement an interface so that you can access the `Id` property:

```
public interface IId
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And then you need to include the generic method in a generic class that has the corresponding type constraint:

```
public RepoClass<TEntity>
   where TEntity : IId
{
   // Define the generic method here
}
```

In this way you don't have to resort to `Reflection`.

If you're using some kind of T4 template,or whatever, to create your POCOs, make them partial classes, so that you can declare the interface in a separate file, like this:

```
public partial MyDomainClass : IId
{
}
```

In this wya, the interface won't be lost when you update your Db Context objects.

And finally, download an use ValueInjecter, for example using Nuget Package Manager, or running `Install-Package ValueInjecter` in the Nuget Package Manager console.

When you include `using Omu.ValueInjecter;` namespace in your code, you'll get an `InjectFrom` extension method on all objects, that allows to automatically copy all the properties from a source object (by matching their names). Don't use `AutoMapper`, or you'll have to solve other problems.

Alternatively, you can check that the object exists in the DB (for security) and use the original object, without copying the properties, i.e.

```
  var updatedObject = ctx.Set<TEntity>().Attach(domainObject);
  ctx.Entry(updatedObject).State = EntityState.Modified;
  ctx.SaveChanges();
```

I prefer this solution, better than the previous one.

Comment: Hello and thanks! This looks interesting but I see two possible problems for me here (I'll have to take a deeper look at the first though, maybe it's not one): (1) I don't know `TEntity` at the point where I pass `domainObject` to my update method, so it's really just an `object` together with its `Type`. Does that then still work? That is, can the CLR make use of the part `DbSet<TEntity>` then? (2) We're working on VM's without internet access sadly.. so I can't use NuGet or anything else.

Comment: (1) `TEntity` is inferred from the received parameter: in your own code, you do: `Type type = domainObj.GetType()`. That means that `domainObj` is a variable of type `Object` holding an instance of a derived type: That's how generics work! (2) Then use the last alternative (from "Alternatively...") which doesn't require `AutoMapper` package. Anyway how did you get EF library into your project? You can do exactly the same with AutoMapper!

Comment: Ah, I thought that I couldn't use generics here because I'd have `DbSet<object>` then. Nice that it works this way! (2) That's the funny thing I don't understand so far: neither `Install-Package` nor NuGet Package Manager; instead, I have to add an ADO.NET Entity Model into the project, then create the model from an existing database, choose Version 6, but don't have to select any DB, but it will add the necessary dll's into the project. I don't know where they come from, since I tried all of the above ;)

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327929/how-to-install-nuget-packages-without-internet-connection